# WIFI auto reconnect Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless

Firstly its worth mentioning that i've trawled the Internet and tried over 15 different ways to fix this already, many of them from this website.

I have a rather unstable WIFI connection (which unfortunately I cannot change).  I run a server from my ubuntu 16.04 box, and I need to find a method which automatically reconnects it to the WIFI when it disconnects, and never stops trying to do so on disconnect.  Are there any new scripts, programs or ideas in 2016 to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I believe it tries to reconnect every 2 minutes. My syslog used to be spammed with searching for new AP message every 2 minutes even when already connected and the neighbour's APs had on profile setup anyway. I had to go through some hops to make the spam disappear.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot change the settings in the router or access point, or do you mean that you have tried every setting available at the driver and it doesn't change the instability? Power saving? 11n disable? Updated firmware? Etc., etc.?

Comment: I don't have access to the WIFI router sadly.  It prompts for password confirmation when it disconnects annoyingly, if I could just get it to continue forever without prompting for password it would resolve the situation..

Comment: Do you mean that the router has some web-based password access, such as at a retail store, or that the router prompts for the password to connect to the SSID?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix On my laptop (Ubuntu 16.04), as well as on my Desktop (Ubuntu 17.04), when my wifi connection is dropped, it shows a messagebox asking me to input my password again, and it's useless to click on the connect button on that box since it doesn't connect. I have to click on the networking icon in the taskbar and select my network from the available networks for it to connect (and it doesn't even ask for a password when reconnecting that way).

Something is wrong in that department.